# Partition Function - TOTAL internal energy vs Average Energy

Tags: partition-function, energy

Given a partition function Z, the books sometimes uses the terms 'total internal energy' and 'average energy' exchangeably. It confuses me to no end.

On one hand they say that Internal energy is average energy:

$$\bar U = -\frac{\partial ln Z}{\partial \beta}$$

Then they use this to calculate specific heat: $C_v = (\frac{\partial U}{\partial t})_V$.

On the other hand they say internal energy is

$$U = \sum \epsilon_p n_p = \int \epsilon \space n_p g_{(\epsilon)}  d\epsilon$$

where $n_p$ is mean number of particles with energy p, $g_{(E)}$ is density of states.

Then they use this to calculate heat capacity.

Which is which?!

Comment: I might be remembering wrong, but aren't they both the same?

Comment: The second equation is correct only for free particles. I also suspect than in the second case, the Hamiltonian is defined as $\sum_p \epsilon_p N_p$ (with $\bar N_p=n_p$), which shows what you want.

Answer (score 4):

The average energy is 
$$\overline{U}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}\log(Z)=-\frac{1}{Z}\frac{\partial Z}{\partial\beta}=\frac{\sum_pg_p\epsilon_p\exp(-\epsilon_p\beta)}{\sum_pg_p\exp(-\epsilon_p\beta)}=\sum_p\epsilon_pP_p$$
where $P_p$ is the probability of being in the $p^\text{th}$ state. Multiplying this by $N$ (the total number of particles) and noting that $n_p=NP_p$ gives the total energy
$$N\overline{U}=\sum \epsilon_p n_p=U.$$
This is where my thermo skills are rusty (or nonexistent); I'm not sure why there isn't a factor of $N$ in your original question (unless $Z$ isn't a single-particle partition function).

Comment: how did you get from the second last step to the last step? $n_p$ is the occupation number.

Comment: I'm bad at thermo so I'm probably leaving something out, but recall that for Boltzmann-distributed populations, you have $P_p=g_p\exp(-\epsilon_p)/Z$ where $P_p$ is the probability of being in the $p^\text{th}$ state ($Z$ is just a normalizing factor, like you learn about in any intro probability math course). I just replaced $P_p$ with $n_p=NP_p$, since it sounds like you're dealing with an entire system of $N$ particles, rather than a single particle. Not sure if that's valid, but I think the real answer probably isn't far off.

Comment: @user44840: In other words, my answer above shows that $N\overline{U}=U$.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus If I understand correctly, the index $p$ refers to single particle states, but $Z$ should be a sum over all $N$-particle states. I guess one should replace $Z\rightarrow Z_1^N$ where $Z_1$ is the single-particle partition function. This produces under the log the factor $N$. But it is only valid for non-interacting systems. Not 100% sure though, feeling a little rusty myself.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've learnt.

According to conversation of energy...

$$U=\sum_i P_i \varepsilon_i$$

...where $P_i=\frac{1}{Z} exp(\beta \varepsilon_i)$ and $\beta=\frac{-1}{k_B T}$

Put it all together and they give us...

$$U=\frac{1}{Z} \sum_i \varepsilon_i exp(\beta \varepsilon_i)$$

Then there's the partial derivative expression for U:

$$U=\frac{\partial log(Z)}{\partial \beta}$$
...where $Z=\sum_i exp(\beta \varepsilon_i)$

$$U=\frac{\partial log(Z)}{\partial \beta}=U=\frac{\partial log(Z)}{\partial Z} \frac{\partial Z}{\partial \beta}=\frac{1}{Z} \sum_i \varepsilon_i exp(\beta \varepsilon_i)$$

Anyway, that's just plain old derivation. I hope it helps clear some things up. To be honest, I'm still trying to understand the underlying physical implications. For me it's a case of failing to grasp the semantics of the math.

Comment: $U = \sum_i P_i \epsilon_i = \bar U$ is the average energy, not the total.